# Why can I not filter it inside my REST API end point

Tags: 2013, development, rest, lookup-column, odata

Inside my Projects list, I have a lookup column named ProgrammeRevissionId that is referenced to my Dept list. When I define the following REST call:

```
http://.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated eq 'Yes'&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId&$orderby= Title asc
```

and I get the following results sample, which is correct:

[image]

When I try to filter based on the ProgrammeRevissionId, as follows:

```
http://../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated eq 'Yes',ProgrammeRevissionId eq '13'&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId&$orderby= Title asc
```

I get an error :

**Http 400 bad request**

Why I can select a lookup column but I can not filter it inside my REST API end point?

Comment: Is `SiteAutomaticallyCreated` a choice column or a boolean?

Comment: @GautamSheth it is a single line text field,, but i do not think it is causing the problem,, as i can filter based on it in-case i am not referencing  ProgrammeRevissionId as mentioned in my original question

Answer (score 7):

Your filter expression looks malformed, you join them by and, not a comma. Try the below.

You'd have a request like:
`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated eq 'Yes' and ProgrammeRevissionId eq '13'&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId&$orderby=Title asc`

These things are easy enough to test in the browser and doing a little investigation on OData protocols and syntax.

As Kai reminded me, you have to expand the projected fields. The comma point I made is still valid. For completeness it would be

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated eq 'Yes' and ProgrammeRevissionId/Id eq '13'&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId/Id&$expand=ProgrammeRevission/Id&$orderby=Title asc`

Comment: i tried your syntax mainly to use 'and' instead of ',' but i got the same error ..

Comment: here is my full api request `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated eq 'Yes' and ProgrammeRevissionId eq '13'&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId&$orderby= Title asc`

Comment: bah forgot the expand as Kai detailed, the comma point is still valid

Comment: your updated code will return "Http 400 bad request" error also ..i am really confused on what is going on? now one point that i can not understand, is that inside my original query i was able to add the ProgrammeRevissionId inside the select without using $expand.. so why i need to use $expand if i want to add the lookup field inside the filter ? thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you want to filter on lookup field, you need to expand those lookup for filtering.
Try the following query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$filter=SiteAut‌​omaticallyCreated eq 'Yes' and ProgrammeRevission/Id eq 13&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevission/Id&$expand=ProgrammeRevission/Id&$orderby= Title asc
```

More info [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API)

Comment: unfortunately i tried your code but it returned "Http 400 bad request" ...  now one point that i can not understand, is that inside my original query i was able to add the ProgrammeRevissionId inside the select without using $expand.. so why i need to do so inside the filter,, in all ways i tried removing the $expand and then adding them but i will keep receiving "Http 400 bad request".. not sure what is going on??

Comment: What is the internal name of `ProgrammeRevission`? In **REST** query, you have to always use internal name of your field. @johnG

Comment: @johnG: It's possible to query lookup id without expand by using `FieldInternalName` + `Id` like you did in your original query. Besides for filtering by lookup column this simply approach doesn't work. In case you are still getting the error, try to escape all uri parts, so your query will be `?$filter=SiteAutomaticallyCreated%20eq%20%27Yes%27&$select=ID,Title,ProgrammeRevissionId&$orderby=%20Title%20asc`